# I am using geocoder module to get lat long of some place, i am just not getting how can i take the result outside the function

Tags: node.js, google-geocoder, node-modules

```
function test(req, res) {
    var loc = [];
    geocoder.geocode("Mohali", function ( err, data ) {
    loc = data;
    }); 
    res.json(loc);
}
```

//Here I am getting empty array. what can i do to get the values outside the geocoder function?

Answer (score 0):

This is an async method, therefore you will want to return in the callback:

```
function test(req, res) {
  var loc = [];
  geocoder.geocode("Mohali", function ( err, data ) {
    loc = data;
    res.json(loc);
  });   
 }
```

Comment: how can i use callback here? is their a  way i can get value where i need?

Comment: What do you mean "where you need"? This will return your json to what I assume is Express. Is your actual code different?